# Can attributes be used with entitiy titles on data flow diagrams?

Tags: diagramming, dataflow-diagram

All. I'm trying to diagram the flow of data between several large, complex systems. I'm putting each system on the data flow diagram as an entity. I also would like to show which entities are public facing, and which are internally facing. Is it proper/correct to add "(internal)" or "(public)" next to each entity title? Such as:

> FileNet (internal)

Is there a better diagram (UML?) that would show, at a high-level, how the systems, and their data, is connected? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question implies you are asking about a specific DFD issue. Since that is not UML I remove the tag from your question. Or re-write it in a way it might belong to UML. The current final question is just opinion based (so OT).

Answer (score -1):

To show the interactions between SW (or in general System-) entities, sequence diagrams are mostly preferable. But they focus on the calling aspect, i.e., control flow. You can also show some internal flows there, when your entites having sub-entities. But you should not mix internal with external views. 
If you want to focus more on the data flow and behaviour on more higher  level of abstraction, an activity diagram is more preferable. Especially, as you don't need the definition of conrete interfaces.